# Labels not displaying correctly

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

In Qt designer when I make my UI's, the UI displays correctly. When I convert it to Python code and run the program it looks different and the text doesn't fit correctly.

QT Designer:

[image]

When I convert it to Python code and run the program:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekvoK.png]

Comment: Could you provide some code? Also you might try making the length of your label longer.

Comment: I've had problems like this before too. Simplest solution is to set a minimum size for each element I think

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because the .ui to .py converter (pyuic) does not use the same methodology as the QtDesigner previewer. This difference not only occurs with the QLabels but with other components, but since they are minimal differences then these are not observable.

A workaround for this case is to use the adjustSize() method after setting the text:

```
the_qlabel.adjustSize()
```